# Error while loading .so file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build an app in Android Studio on Windows. This app uses precompiled .so files, which are kept inside the `jniLibs` directory.

When I try to run my app I get the following error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" not found

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not clear from the question exactly which libraries you're using and how they were built. Are you trying to load an x86-64 .so file on a non-x86-64 device?

Comment: Could you show us how do you load your libraries? for example gradle files,  if you are using emulator or physical devices, or which is the way that you are loading libraries in execution time.